# Could not build wheels for pycuda

Tags: python, pip, pycuda

Receiving an error during pip pycuda installation on ubuntu as follows:

```
command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycuda
Failed to build pycuda
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycuda, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: [edit]  and show the full text of the error message, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by doing:

For Python 2.x use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For Python 2.7 use:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

For Python 3.x use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

or for a specific version of Python 3, replace x with the minor version in

```
sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

```
export CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/targets/x86_64-linux/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
pip install pycuda
```

Comment: any solution for windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev` also works for `pycuda fatal error: pyconfig.h` case.

Many thanks to @user19594699